# Вопрос по датапикеру ангуляр материал

Tags: angular2

Вопрос по ссылке.
Вопрос по датапикеру ангуляр материал
https://youtu.be/mMDeXEDTuo0

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вопрос в видео посылке